# xhprof not working for php rabbitmq consumers

Tags: php, symfony, xhprof

I have rabbitmq consumers written in php with symfony2-framework, and I'm trying to see the inner workings and issues of the system with xhprof. Problem is that it's not saving anything into the mongodb. Mongo is totally empty.

I've tried to set the auto_prepend_file(which adds the necessary header-file) in php.ini, the applications .htaccess -file, and the apaches virtual hosts.

I set the profiler to profile every request and it profiles everything else just fine, eeexcept the rabbitmq-consumers running in the background. But why not?

For instance, I called phpinfo.php -file and it profiled it perfectly, but not the consumers, nope.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Xhprof profiles the data when the script exists which is kinda never for the rabbitmq consumers, since they are processes running in the background.

So: One solution would be to add the appropriate begin and exit -codes from the header-file in to the scripts that are running, but this is way too much trouble for me.

I ended up using PHP's own [XDebug](https://xdebug.org/) with visualizing tool: [Webgrind](https://github.com/jokkedk/webgrind).

Comment: See my extra answer

Answer (score 1):

Xhprof does not *forcibly* save the profile data when the script exits. But **when** you instruct him to do so. Lot of setups includes something like from https://github.com/patrickallaert/xhprof#profile-your-page, using `register_shutdown_function()`, which gets executed at the end of a script.

But it is up to you to put `xhprof_enable()` / `xhprof_disable()` around the code that you want to profile. It is also perfectly valid in a loop, example:

```
<?php

while (true) {
    // Fetch a message from the queue

    // Start profiling
    xhprof_enable();

    // [treatment of your message]

    // End profiling and dump the result
    file_put_contents("/tmp/" . uniqid() . ".your_app.xhprof", serialize(xhprof_disable()));
}
```

Comment: I kinda referenced to this in my own answer when I said: "One solution would be to add the appropriate begin and exit -codes from the header-file in to the scripts that are running". Not very clear, admitted. Upvoting this for those who have the option to add these code blocks. I found the webgrind to be more suitable for my needs.

Comment: Ha, indeed, was not very clear, feel free to edit your answer for posterity.

Note that Xhprof comes with less overhead than XDebug and makes the profiling more precise and less intrusive. However XDebug's generated files are more "standard" and permits other GUI to open it.